# Need to convert a string input from the user into different variables to use

Tags: c

Here is a function for some code im working on in C. Right now it accepts 2 different user inputs and stores them as city and distance. What I want is for the user to input only once. For example "Enter the city name and distance from previous city: Arlington 200". I need to separate that string into values for city and distance. I think I need to use tokens but im not sure how.

```
void addCity ()
{
char city[30];
int distance;

printf("Enter city name : ");
scanf("%s",city);
printf("Enter distance from previous city: ");
scanf("%d",&distance);
printf("The city has been added.\n");

if(root == NULL){
root = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
strcpy(root->city, city);
root->distance = distance;
root->next = NULL;
}
else
{

struct node *currentNode = root;
struct node *newNode = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
while(currentNode->next!=NULL)
{
currentNode = currentNode->next;
}

strcpy(newNode->city, city);
newNode->distance = distance;

currentNode->next = newNode;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `sscanf`

Comment: Indentation please. While it's irrelevant for the compiler, it does help humans to read and understand the code.

Comment: Another couple of notes: In the `else` case, where do you initialize `newNode->next`? And [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt for both at once:

```
printf("Enter the city name and distance from previous city: ");
scanf("%s %d",city, &distance);
```

Comment: Will this method work with spaces? I"m about to try.

Comment: I would make sure to limit that to 30 characters and check the return value, but good answer.

Comment: @AdrianGuerra Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @AdrianGuerra The `"%s"` format reads space-delimited "words" anyway, so it's really no different at all from `scanf("%s",city); scanf("%d",&distance);`